# Google Cloud Logging

Tags: google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-tasks

I am following [this](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/quickstart) quickstart tutorial for Google Cloud Tasks. I create the project, service accounts, and queue like the tutorial describes. I am able to push items to the queue, and they get de-queued.

I run `gcloud app logs tail`, to view my logs, but nothing is ever logged out. I have tried enabling logs on the UI, hoping that would change something, but it does not. What else do I need to do to be able to have the logs show in my terminal?

Comment: Check if you turned on [logging.](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/logging) You can do that by using the following command ` gcloud tasks queues create [QUEUE_ID] --log-sampling-ratio=1.0 ` or `gcloud tasks queues update [QUEUE_ID] --log-sampling-ratio=1.0`

Answer (score 0):

It may sometimes happen that the logging is not turned on. Check if you turned on [logging](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/logging). You can do that by using the following command `gcloud tasks queues create [QUEUE_ID] --log-sampling-ratio=1.0` or `gcloud tasks queues update [QUEUE_ID] --log-sampling-ratio=1.0`